# How to validate Amazon access key and secret key is correct?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I wrote a function to validate the AWS keys by just creating the ec2 connection object

```
import boto.ec2
try:
    ec2Conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region, aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
    return ec2Conn
except boto.exception.EC2ResponseError as e:
    print e
```

But even if the secret key is wrong still it creates the ec2 connection object.

So I validate the access key and secret key by fetching the regions,

```
region = ec2Conn.get_all_regions()
```

Is there any method or way rather than the fetching region to validate the access key and secret key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to verify AWS credentials is to actually use them to sign a request and see if it works.  You are correct that simply creating the connection object tells you nothing because it doesn't perform a request.  So you have to pick some request that should always work, won't return a huge amount of data, and doesn't create any resources on the server side.  I think the `get_all_regions()` request is a pretty good choice.

Comment: The STS "GetCallerIdentity" API call is better suited if you only need to validate the credentials and not verify actual permissions. This call does not require any permissions to be used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html

Answer (score 0):

`get_all_regions()` works, but like @Paradigm suggested in a comment. The GetCallerIdentity is the right call to make.

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html